# Prevent p:dataTable from shrinking too much when empty

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

I use a Primefaces DataTable to display some data. I also allow filtering and sorting. In Internet Explorer, setting the filter to a value that returns no results (empty table) shrinks the table too much and scroll bars appear:
[image]

This is of course very ugly. In all other browsers it works perfectly fine. So this might be a problem with the version of Internet Explorer or Primefaces that I use, but changing those is not really an option.

I probably need some CSS shenanigans to work around this. I tried using height/width and min-height/min-width and also the scrollWidth / scrollHeight and scrollable attributes of the p:dataTable but that didn't to the trick.

Any suggestions?

Edit:
Using Primefaces 6.2.17, Internet Explorer 21H1

Comment: "this might be a problem with the version of Internet Explorer or Primefaces that I use" without that information we cannot say it is. Did you try with PF 11.0.0-RC2?

Comment: I added version numbers of PF and IE. As I wrote, upgrading it is not really an option, I'm pretty much looking for some quick & dirty CSS workaround.

Comment: I that case share the rendered HTML

Comment: Trying to decide which part of the HTML to post made me stumble upon a solution to the problem, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While looking through the rendered HTML I noticed that the `<div>` the dataTable was rendered inside (`<div class="ui-datatable-tablewrapper">`) had this CSS set:

```
.ui-datatable-tablewrapper {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Setting it to `overflow: visible;` in my .css file solved my problem:

Comment: oncomplete is an unconventional way of setting CSS. Why not create a custom style sheet?

Comment: Putting the .ui-datatable-tablewrapper {
    overflow: auto;
} 
in its own .css file (or into the jsf style="" attribute) had no effect. I assume it always got overwritten by the the dataTable. Adding !important also didn't do the trick, thats why I'm doing it with the ajax event

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles

Comment: Thanks! now it works without the p:ajax element, I have updated my answer accordingly